# Copy a ndarray into another ndarray at a given position

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In numpy how can I copy a 2d array into another 2d array at a given x and y coordinate?

For example, I have this 7 by 7 array of zeros:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

And I want to place this 2 by 2 array of ones on row 2 and column 3 of the previous array, resulting in:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With item-slice setting:

```
A = numpy.zeros((7,7))
B = numpy.ones((2,2))
A[2:4, 3:5] = B
```